# MVC Authorize with roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

I want only users with specific roles to see a page, I have tried
`[Authorize]`, which works, but when I try `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` I get an error:

> Access denied
>
> You do not have access to this resource.

even if I am logged in & got the role "Admin"

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: How do you ensure you got the role of admin?

Comment: Can you publish the code for configuring the identity service?